# Cpanel Nodejs Can't acquire lock for app: %(app)s

Tags: node.js, linux, express, cpanel, web-hosting

`I encounter this error whenever I want to start the server.

"Can't acquire lock for app: %(app)s"

I want to install nodejs server on my Linux server with cpanel, but when I try npm install I get the following error

When I delete the .lock file, reinstall it and click npm install, I encounter this error again. What causes this error?

Server Nodejs Versiyon = 18.16

my main file is server.js DB: MYSQL

My Package.json:

```
    {
      "name": "backend",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "nodemon server.js"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
        "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
        "mysql": "^2.18.1",
        "mysql2": "^3.6.1",
        "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
        "path": "^0.12.7"
      }}`
```

I tried reinstalling but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you